# How to use the Remesh modifier correctly

Tags: remesh

I imported a .svg file into blender which created six curves. I converted one of those curves into a mesh. I applied the Remesh modifier to this mesh, but it appears to have no effect regardless of the settings I choose. Is there a better way to fix this topology?
[image]

Comment: If you want to simplify the topology, select all and X > Limited DIssolve?

Comment: Voxel Remesh doesn't work with planar or non-manifold meshes

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The Remesh modifier doesn't work with 2d planes. If you want uniform quads you have to make it 3d first by extruding it while it's still a curve, extruding it in edit mode or giving it Solidify modifier. Then you can give it a Remesh modifier set to Sharp mode and apply them both. Then in Edit mode you can select one of the top faces and click Shift+G->Coplanar to select all the other top facing faces. Then just Invert the selection and delete the others to get the flat plane with quad topology.

I'm sure you can also do this with geometry nodes if you'd want a non destructive approach but it's probably more work than it needs to be